# How to use iterate link from tHashInput

Tags: talend

The schema of "Global_variable_hash" contains "filename" field. The hash itself contains multiple records which are populated earlier in the job. I want to use "filename" field in tFileInputExcel_1 to dynamically set filename of excel for each record. How can I access this variable in tFileInputExcel_1?

[image]

I want to execute tFileInputExcel_1 connected flow for each record present in "Global_variable_hash". Hence, I need to access the "filename" variable for each record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a tFlowToIterate component between tHashInput and tFileInputExcel
Then in tFileInputExcel, you can access your variable which will be listed as a global Variable associated with tFlowToIterate (ctrl+space to get access to component variables).
You can use default parameters in tFlowToIterate. You won't have anything to configure in it.

Comment: If that is the case, then "Iterate" link on tHashInput does not make sense, as I anyway have to insert tFlowToIterate in between?

Comment: yes, never found any utility to those iterate links, except for a few dedicated components (tLoop, tFlowToiterate,tFileList..)